# can't save file in android file system

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm trying to capture a photo with the camera and save it (to be previewed later) and it seems to work with the emulator but when I use it on my GalaxyS - it doesn't save the file (I use `RootExplorer` to check) and there's no preview.

What am I doing wrong?

Code for saving the file:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      FileOutputStream outStream = null;
      try {
        // Write to SD Card
        String filename = "captured_image.jpg";

        Log.d("@@--File name--@@", filename);
        outStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); // <9>
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // <10>
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
```

Code for displaying:

```
ImageView imagePrev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_capturedimagepreview_preview);


        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openFileInput("captured_image.jpg"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        imagePrev.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Does logcat show an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found the problem. 
instead of `outStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);` i should use `outStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`

but now i'm facing a new one - the file seems to be corrupted cause when i open it with the Android's viewer it's just black and its size is always 18474 bytes.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing the image? Have you tried using an absolute path?  Do you have the read/write external permission in the manifest? 
I used something like this in my program to store an image in a directory the same as my package name.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
File imagePath = new File(path,"capture_image.jpg");
```

**EDIT:**
If its your first time using the sd card for your given package name you will need to create the directory before trying to write to it.

Comment: your way will save the file under /dscard/ whereas i want to save it under /data/data/package.name/files/. the mathod `openFileOutput()` allows me to create a file there.

in my menifest i have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

i tried your code and it didn't work (even on the emulator). maybe i need additional permissions?

Comment: If it is caused by a permission issue it will show in the logcat output, please provide that for us.

Comment: hmmm... i understand now but I have no idea why its not working. let us know what it was if you figure it out

Comment: i'm trying it your way but i'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: `8-31 18:12:09.264: DEBUG/@@--Package--@@(19375): cs.workshop.solvedroid
08-31 18:12:09.334: DEBUG/@@--Image Path--@@(19375): /sdcard/cs.workshop.solvedroid/capture_image2.jpg
08-31 18:12:09.334: WARN/System.err(19375): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/cs.workshop.solvedroid/capture_image2.jpg
08-31 18:12:09.334: WARN/System.err(19375):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:244)`

Comment: this is the code i used. i'm sorry it looks so messy... i'm just not sure how to format it right in comments :/

`File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() );
File imagePath = new File(path,"capture_image2.jpg");
        if(!imagePath.exists()){
         imagePath.mkdirs();
         imagePath.createNewFile();
        }
        Log.d("@@--Image Path--@@", imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        outStream.write(data);
        outStream.close();`